# How to get values of an array in a text label instead of the key

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, label

I have a text label that change when i press a button, the label does change with the use of a array, but instead of the value of the array i get the keys of the array.

What should i do to get the values?

This is the code:

```
    NSString*path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"plist"];
    words = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString*generateRandomLabel =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arc4random_uniform([ words count])];
    [self.randomLabel setText:generateRandomLabel];
```

Comment: Um, wait... there are no keys in an array... or are you writing your iOS app in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString*path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"plist"];
words = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString*generateRandomLabel = nil;
if ([words count] >0)
    generateRandomLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([ words count]-1)]]; // To make sure object is not out of bounds of array add -1
else
    generateRandomLabel = @"No values in array";
[self.randomLabel setText:generateRandomLabel];
```